# Locomotive with mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, locomotivecms

I am planning to use Locomotive for a project...But as the official website says it cannot work with MySQL. However my requirement is to use it with MySQL.

Has any one used it with mySQL? Any pointers or advises would be great. Thanks.

Cheers,
Abi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locomotive uses Mongoid - which is an ORM for MongoDB. As such, you cannot use it with MySQL at all, since it leverages some features (dynamic attributes), which traditional RDBMS databases (such as MySQL) do not support.

That being said, MongoDB is pretty easy to install, so if you can get around your requirement of MySQL, then you should have no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Decoupling Locomotive from MongoDB would be no small task at the moment, which is not to say that it is impossible.

Regarding your requirement of MySQL, if you are working on incorporating Locomotive into a larger web-application, one thing to consider is that your non-Locomotive models can still live in MySQL regardless of where Locomotive keeps its data.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know it wont be possible to use locomotive only with mysql as it use heavily mondodb.

However it's not a problem to build your app living together with locomotive and use what ever orm you like.
Just configure your database.yml and the magic will happend ;)

cheers,

Gregory horion